# Add class to @html.DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a few dropdown models that I need to add the bootstrap form-control class to.  I am struggling converting this string to accept the class.

I'd appreciate the help.

I've put

```
, new { @class = "form-control"}
```

everywhere in the line to no success.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedSourceAccount,  new 
SelectList(Model.AllWithdrawalAccounts.Select(x => new {Value = x.Id, Text = 
x.NameAndAvailableBalance}), "Value", "Text"), Model.SelectedSourceAccount)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try (note you do not need the `.Select(..)` when creating the select list)

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedSourceAccount, new SelectList(Model.AllWithdrawalAccounts, "Id", "NameAndAvailableBalance"), new { @class = "form-control"})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedSourceAccount, new 
SelectList(Model.AllWithdrawalAccounts.Select(x => new {Value = x.Id, Text = 
x.NameAndAvailableBalance}),string.Empty, new { @class = "dropdown" })
```

Comment: Don't give code only answers. Explain the answer briefly, so that it will be helpful for others also.

Answer (score 0):

As there are multiple overloaded method for `dropdown`, I think you've used a wrong overloaded method. You can use a correct overloaded method provided.